# Unable to select element when document is ready

Tags: jquery

I have a function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    listproject() ;
});
```

`listproject()` is a function returning a string of unordered list which I have appended to the document.
Until here everything is ok. I have the correct list in my HTML view .

Just after `listproject()` I have added a code line for displaying my first `<li>` value, but I have undefined as result.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    listproject() ;
    alert($('li:first').val());
});
```

If I log in to my JavaScript console and I choose watch expression, my jQuery object `$('li:first')` exist.

here is my return string in list project following your requests

```
<ul><li id="205">205<ul><li id="206">206<ul><li id="208">208</li><li id="209">209</li><li id="211">211<ul><li id="212">212</li><li id="213">213</li></ul></li></ul></li><li id="207">207<ul><li id="210">210</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
```

I append this return to an existing div in my html code , this is what doing my listproject() function , and the result is ok .

Edit:

after your requests here is my function listproject() following with makeTree function which return to listproject() the string of unordered list :

```
function listproject() {
   $.post("/portail/project/home/getProjectList",
        function (d) {

            var pl = $("#tree").empty();

            if (d.length == 0) {

                pl.append($("<div>").addClass("align_center").html("there is no project"));
                return;
            }
           pl.append(makeTree(d,0));

      },
        "json"
    );


}

 function makeTree( a,level) {
            r = '' ;
            for ( i in a ) {
            if (a[i]['parentid'] == level ) {
            r = r + '<li id='+'"'+a[i]['id']+'"'+'>'+ a[i]['name'] + makeTree(a,a[i]['id'] ) + '</li>';
            }
           }
           if (r==''){r=''; }  

           else { r= '<ul>' + r + '</ul>' ;}

           return r;
            }
```

Now you have all the element for responding and thinks again .

Comment: Are you using ajax to get the unordered list?. You could post the code for the listproject().

Comment: What does the listproject function look like? This may be because you're appending the list at doc ready, so you need to use .on() http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: ur complete code or fiddle?

Comment: Please don't bold your entire question.. It doesn't get it more noticed.

Comment: i have edited my question to be more explicit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the `$('li:first')` part is valid, but the `.val()` bit isn't. They're supposed to work on form items, such as checkboxes and selects. See [`.val()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Try `$('li:first').text()` or `$('li:first').html()`

**Edit:** The reason why you still get an undefined error is because your list elements are appended in an AJAX request. As the name suggests that's done asynchronously, the alert is called before your POST has completed.

So you need a way to ensure you're calling the alert *after* the post call has completed. The basic way is as part of the anonymous function you passed in:

```
function listproject() {
  $.post("/portail/project/home/getProjectList",
    function (d) { 
      /* [your existing code here] */

      // That's all done, so now I can query it...
      alert($('li:first').text());
    }
  });
}
```

Alternatively use [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (much better):

```
function listproject() {
  $.post("/portail/project/home/getProjectList",
    function (d) { 
      /* [your existing code here] */
    }
  }).done(function() {
      // That's all done, so now I can query it...
      alert($('li:first').text());
  });
}
```

Another tweak here is that you could make listproject return the deferred and can be used outside of that function:

```
function listproject() {
  var deferred = $.post("/portail/project/home/getProjectList",
    function (d) { 
      /* [your existing code here] */
    }
  });
  return deferred;
}
var deferred = listproject();
deferred.done(function() {
   // That's all done, so now I can query it...
   alert($('li:first').text());
});
```

Comment: result with text() is empty ans with html() is undefined !!

Comment: @MbarekOussama Ok, I think to assist further you'll need to update your question to show us what your listproject() function is doing.

Comment: ok think you for your idea , now every function which need an <li> element i'll write it inside my post request .

Answer (score 1):

A `li` does not have a `val()` - that method is used to get the value of a *field* (such as an `input` or a `select`)

You probably want `.html()`

```
alert($('li:first').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

`li` elements don't have value. To get their content use `.html()` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

val return value of a form element, so only those elements like input select textarea return something with that function in case of a li you need to use text or html

```
alert($('li:first').text());
```

or

```
alert($('li:first').html());
```